# How can I hide a panel that is on a SplitContainer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to hide panel2 on a split container and have panel1 utilize the space. I was hoping setting Panel2Collapsed would do the trick, but no luck. Ideas?

Comment: What actually happens when you set Panel2Collapsed to true?  Does Panel2 stay visible?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This worked for me on a similar situation:

```
splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
splitContainer1.Panel2.Hide();
```

I wanted the second panel to not be visible at all in some cases, so I implemented it this way.

Comment: If you don't set the SplitterDistance and calling Hide(), which part of Panel2 is visible?

Comment: If I recall correctly, if you didn't set the SplitterDistance, then at  the far end of Panel1 the mouse cursor would change, making it evident that there is another panel there.

Comment: but what happens when the user resizes the form

Comment: @Nikos: Hmm... I can't recreate that :-/  That kind of issue exists with the `Splitter` control, but I thought the whole purpose of the SplitContainer was to do away with those issues...

Comment: @CrashCodes: If the splitcontainer is docked, or properly anchored it will resize with the form, and Panel1 will stay docked to fill the entire splitcontainer.

Comment: Okay. Tried it works great. I started removing lines to see which one did the trick; and I'm back down to splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true; Fun stuff.

Comment: @CrashCodes: Meaning that just setting Panel2Collapsed works?

Comment: @Daniel L: You're right, it doesn't do that! I checked it out and most probably setting the SplitterDistance equal to the total width is most probably just redundant.

Comment: Thanks guys, at least I know that I'm not crazy!  Glad you got it to work :]

Answer (score 3):

Setting `Panel2Collapsed` property to `true` in the form designer and programatically both work as you want them to (i.e. Panel1 then occupies all of the space)... so there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
            this.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Hide();
            this.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Height = 0;
            this.splitContainerControl1.IsSplitterFixed = true;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

splitContainer1.PanelVisibility = SplitPanelVisibility.Panel1

Comment: No such property exists.

Comment: It works for Devexpress SplitContainerControl. Maybe here is not right place but it worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio 2017 it is a little more trick. This is what I got to work for me.  MyControl is inside panel1.

```
'vb.net:

MySplitContainer.Panel2Collapsed = True
MySplitContainer.Panel2.Hide()
MySplitContainer.SplitterDistance = MySplitContainer.Height
MySplitContainer.Panel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom
MyControl.Height = MySplitContainer.Height

'for C# just add a semi-colon onto the end of each line and it should work.
```

Answer (score -3):

Try setting panel2.Visible = false.